# Can the word "if" be used in this situation?

Tags: conjunctions

Is the sentence "It's for if you fall in a lake." grammatically correct? I'm curious about the beginning of the sentence "for if you" mainly.

Comment: I think it's *In case you fall in a lake.*

Comment: @Subjunctive I think it's okay, I just cant think of any situations where "it" is prefered over "this/that". Your version is more formal.

Comment: I think it's OK in a very informal situation.  I can imagine a conversation:  *"What's that for?"*  "It's for if you fall in a lake."

Comment: Changing "if" to "when" would make it sound better. And more comical. "It's for when you fall into a lake."

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer to your question: no, it's not grammatically correct.

"It's for" should be followed by an object (the grammar part) or an object phrase. Examples are "you", "safety", "falling into a lake" or "the case that you fall from the boat".

"If you fall in a lake" is not an object phrase. It is a conditional phrase. You could use it to place a condition after the main phrase, but the main phrase should be complete.

For example, you could say "It's for keeping you safe if you fall into a lake".

As a side note, I assume you mean fall *into* a lake. Falling *in* a lake is grammatically correct but logically weird.

Answer (score 0):

> It's for if you fall in a lake.

is OK. To expand a bit:

> I brought along a life jacket. It is for (you), if you fall *into the* lake.

meaning "If you fall in a lake you will need it."